# dpkg: error: reading package info file '/usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status': Is a directory

Tags: terminal, debian, dpkg

I want to install apt_1.0.9.8.1_amd64.deb package but when I try `dpkg -i apt_1.0.9.8.1_amd64.deb` at first the error is requested operation requires superuser privilege and then after I sudo it `dpkg: error: reading package info file '/usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status': Is a directory`

Answer (score 0):

I understand Debian uses `status` to keep some information about installed packages. Try running the following commands :

```
sudo mv /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status.ko
sudo cp /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status-old /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```